# Telerik RadGrid security vulnerabilities

Tags: telerik, radgrid, rad-controls

We have an application which is using Telerik RadGrid controls - RadGrid.net2 dll.

Our security team has reported vulnerabilities in this application and a lot of them are in these RadControls, for example `RadGrid.js` client DOM stored code injection. They are looking us to fix these.

What is the solution for this? Since it is a third party dll and its Javascript is all minimized and bundled we cannot fix this.

Comment: What vulnerability are you seeing? Telerik's forums would be the best way to address this. They're fairly responsive and will address it if needed.